# codesigning for KernelExtension in OSx10.10

Tags: osx-yosemite, code-signing, kernel-extension

IF we sign a kext in 10.10 OSx with dev certificate, will that signing work in other previous OSx versions?
if not then what is the solution to make a kext binary signed compatible to all OSx version ? do we sign diff diff binaries on diff diff versions of OSx, or the same binary signed on the diff diff OSx version?

Answer (score 1):

Signed 64-bit kexts will work on 10.10, 10.9 and 10.8. Unsigned kexts, including universal kexts, will work up to 10.8. If you need to support older *and* newer versions than 10.8, you will need at least 2 versions of the kext. If kext is not required for booting, a convenient way to do it is to place a signed version with the same bundle ID, but a higher bundle version number and with a dependency on 10.9's KPIs in /Library/Extensions, and the legacy (unsigned, universal) kext in /System/Library/Extensions. Only 10.9 and newer look in /Library/Extensions. If your kext is required for booting (e.g. storage controller driver, or dependency of a storage controller driver) then you may have issues with /Library/Extensions, and you'll need to install both versions in /SLE, just with different file names.

Note also that you'll usually want to build each kext against the SDK of the OLDEST supported OSX version. The "deployment target" doesn't work well for kexts, and you'll find that e.g. most kexts will not load on 10.6 if built against the 10.8 SDK even with a 10.6 deployment target. If you want to support features only available in newer versions of the kext, you may need even more variants than the signed/unsigned split.

Comment: I read somewhere that from 10.10 OSx onward signing of Kext has been made mandatory, till 10.9 its optional otherwise Kext will not be loaded. So i had to subscribe the Mac OSx developer portal to get the cetificate for code signing. Could you tell me how do we get that,please. I have private key/ public key and a certificate with usage extention( all I found in Keychain, not sure if this is the one that we need to send to apple developer portal.  :\ ). could you please tell me what is the exact procedure?

Comment: Have you applied for the special kext signing certificate? Your "developer id" certificate does not automatically entitle you to sign kexts. Once you 've been approved for that, you'll need to re-issue the cert, then sign your kext with that.

Comment: FWIW, the user will see a warning even with 10.9, so you should definitely sign kexts to be deployed on 10.9. It's a requirement for any kexts installed in /Library/Extensions

Comment: I have not applied for any certificate so far, as i am not aware of where to apply for them. i just logged into my apple id which is registered to Mac OSx developer.

Comment: You need to apply here. It took about 4 weeks to be approved in my case. https://developer.apple.com/contact/kext/

Comment: The link says "we 'll be back soon"

Comment: You'll probably need to wait until sometime after the WWDC keynote until the developer portal comes back online. Try in the PDT afternoon.